# Windows Phone 7 - passing values between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to send the values between the pages using :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ABC.xaml?name=" + Company + "&city=" + City , UriKind.Relative));
```

Here the Company and City values are passed to the next page, somehow the Company names like "ABC & Ltd" is not passing properly,it just passes the "ABC" to next page. Basically the portion after "&" is dropped.

Is there an option here to format this ??? Or should i write a logic for this ??

Help needed !

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If any of your query strings contain characters that are considered invalid in a Uri what you're doing will fail, as you've discovered. You need to use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) to escape any illegal characters first. Change the code you've posted to the following:

```
NavigationService.Navigate( new Uri( String.Format( "/ABC.xaml?name={0}&city={1}",
          Uri.EscapeDataString( Company ), Uri.EscapeDataString( City ) ), 
          UriKind.Relative ) );
```

The escaped strings are automatically *unescaped* when you read them using `NavigationContext.QueryString`, so there's no need to call `Uri.UnescapeDataString` explicitly.

Comment: Why are you using EscapeDataString instead of EscapeUriString?

Comment: @Clément I read on some blog somewhere that the former works in some cases that the latter doesn't, when it comes to navigation on Windows Phone. Unfortunately, I can't find the link now.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` character is treated as a special character in query strings as a means of separating values. It needs to be escaped into `%26`.

For more information on how to escape URLs easily using [`Uri.EscapeUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

For example:

```
string Company = "ABC & D";
string City = "Falls Church";
string escaped = Uri.EscapeUriString("/ABC.xaml?name=" + Company + "&city=" + City);
var uri = new Uri(escaped, UriKind.Relative);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding... It was helpful !!

Answer (score 0):

You Could also pass parameters to you App.xaml.cs code where you can define global values that you can access throughout your app,

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Community/2011/08/25/passing-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-7/

Comment: please mark the answer as useful if you found use out of my link thanks,