# Windows Phone 7 - passing values between pages

Tags: windows-phone-7

I saw some previous post about this but i still don't understand. I have Three pages and i need to add all the user input IE car1, car2 , car3, and on the third page display a message of the totals. I would greatly appreciate any assistance. So to Recap i would need to add both values from the input on the two pages and display the total on the third.

Comment: how are you navigating between the pages? User inputs some details on Page1, then he navigates to Page2, enters some details and then navigates to Page3?

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new
            Uri("/Page1.xaml",
            UriKind.Relative));   So its like this i have two players. and i have 8 textboxes for each player for each page. on the last page i have a results that i need to grab the totals from the 1st and 2nd page.

Comment: @EricMacDonald take a look at these threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691899
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194993

Answer (score 0):

The only way out it seems is using IsolatedStorage to store those values in the textboxes. Since there is not a huge amount of data you need to store, you can have a look at that. You can read up about it over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and about its usage over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh821020.aspx)